# How to get Username and User Profile Picture from Facebook API in unity engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to implement a user login in my unity game but I am unable to get the user profile picture from their Facebook id. **The username is showing but not the profile picture**. It is showing blank. I am also not getting any errors!
The sprite of the image is changing but not displaying on the screen.
Here is the code:

```
void DealWithFbMenus(bool isLoggedIn)
{
    if (isLoggedIn)
    {
        FB.API("/me?fields=first_name", HttpMethod.GET, DisplayUsername);
        FB.API("/me/picture?type=med", HttpMethod.GET, DisplayProfilePic);
    }
}

void DisplayUsername(IResult result)
{
    if (result.Error == null)
    {
        string name = "" + result.ResultDictionary["first_name"];
        FB_userName.text = name;
        Debug.Log("" + name);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(result.Error);
    }
}

void DisplayProfilePic(IGraphResult result)
{
    if (result.Error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Profile Pic");
        FB_userDp.sprite = Sprite.Create(result.Texture, new Rect(0, 0, 128, 128), new Vector2());
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(result.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Sprite.Create`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) takes

> **rect**     Rectangular section of the texture to use for the sprite.

I suspect that your hard coded `128 x 128` pixels is just a section and not the entire texture depending on the actual image dimensions of the picture.

And it also takes

> **pivot**     Sprite's pivot point relative to its graphic rectangle.

You are using `new Vector2()` which means the bottom left corner. In general for profile pictures I would rather assume that the pivot should be the **center** of the texture and use

```
Vector2.one * 0.5f
```

or

```
new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)
```

So asuming the download itself actually works and as you say you don't get errors you would probbaly rather use e.g.

```
FB_userDp.sprite = Sprite.Create(result.Texture, new Rect(0, 0, result.Texture.width, result.Texture.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
```

or if your goal is to use a square section no matter the dimenions you could use

```
var size = Mathf.Min(result.Texture.width, result.Texture.height);
FB_userDp.sprite = Sprite.Create(result.Texture, new Rect(0, 0, size, size), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
```